# iOS 10 zooming issue

Tags: ios, iphone, ios10, zooming

I need to capture 2 images:
1. zoomed jpeg image
2. RAW image

My device is iPhone 6s with iOS 10.

As iOS can't capture RAW when videoZoomFactor is not 1.0, I need to set it to 1.0 before RAW capture.

The problem is that after I set videoZoomFactor to 1.0 it's applied not immediately, but with delay. And the biggest problem is that delay is bigger in low-light conditions! Office light - about 50 ms, low-light about 200-400 ms. So now I have to make a delay before RAW capture to avoid crashes in didFinishProcessingRawPhotoSampleBuffer.

Maybe there is a way to get an event that zoom level is really set to 1.0 or smth else?

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code to reset zooming:

```
NSError *error = nil;
    if ([self.videoDevice respondsToSelector:@selector(setVideoZoomFactor:)]) {
        if ( [self.videoDevice lockForConfiguration:&error] ) {
            self.videoDevice.videoZoomFactor = 1.0;
            [self.videoDevice unlockForConfiguration];
        }
    }
```